# How to add a "CRM invoice" custom attribute into the invoice page in Magento Sales section?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, create-invoice

I want to make a **plugin** or a **functionality** that is adding to the invoice section(after pushing the button Invoice from an Order) that it allows me to add a CRM invoice ID. The attribute has to be edited by the admin of the store admin.

I want to display on the PDF that is generated for the invoice, this ID instead of Invoice ID. The CRM invoice ID is not a range and it has to be a number that I can set.

Is there a paid plugin or a free plugin for this?

This is not duplicate because what I want to do is not explain in the linked post. I am trying to add in the admin interface a field where I can store a value to show later on in the custom PDF invoice that I've created. The Linked post is telling me how to add a custom filed to an order but I do not find there all the necessary data to make this happen. I've made a lot of tests with no success.

I would like to discuss and make test with other developers that are better than me in this case and go trough the functionality step by step, but I would like to have the possibility to ask .

Comment: This is not duplicate because what I want to do is not explain in the linked post. I am trying to add in the admin interface a field where I can store a value to show later on in the custom PDF invoice that I've created. The Linked post is telling me how to add a custom filed to an order but I do not find there all the necessary data to make this happen. I've made a lot of tests with no success.